# Groups of order at most $5$

Tags: group-theory

This was an exercise given by a teacher in a class; I knew its answer in other elementary as well as with advanced theorems. But, my question is the way exercise stated and expects something. The exercise is following:

> Let $a,b$ be non-commuting elements of a group. Then 
>   (1) show that $1,a,b,ab,ba$ are distinct. (2) Conclude that groups of order up to $5$ are abelian.

My question is *how (1) implies (2)*? [I know how to prove (1).]

Statement (1) certainly implies that groups of order at most $4$ are abelian; but it may imply that *group of order $5$ can be non-abelian* (I know this is not the case!)

Is there a small trick to conclude (2) from (1)?

Comment: Perhaps one needs to consider inverses as well?

Comment: Another possibility is that the wording "up to 5" is not meant to Include 5.

Comment: Is Lagrange's theorem an allowed tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1,a,b,ab,ba$ are all the elements of the group, consider $x\mapsto ax$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 x & 1 & a &  b & ab & ba \\
ax & a & ? & ab & ?  & ? \\
\end{array}
$$
The key point is that the bottom row must be a permutation of the top row.

Consider $a^2$:

- $a^2$ cannot be $a$ because $a\ne1$ (and $a$ is already in the bottom row).
- $a^2$ cannot be $b$ because $a$ commutes with $a^2$ but not with $b$.
- $a^2$ cannot be $ab$ or $ba$ because $a\ne b$.

So, $a^2=1$ and so $a\cdot ab=a^2b=b$, leaving
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 x & 1 & a &  b & ab & ba \\
ax & a & 1 & ab & b  & ? \\
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, $a\cdot ba=ba$, which cannot happen because $a\ne1$.